# How do I set up an Arris NVG558HX (Verizon) router/gateway so that my existing TP-Link Omada router can remain in service?

Tags: router, bridge

I have a home network that uses a TP-Link router, switches, and access points.  I would like to be able to connect them to an Arris NVG558HX (Verizon) router/gateway.  I currently use a DSL modem/router, and I was able to set it to bridge mode so that my TPLink router would control the addresses of my devices.  I have spent far too many hours on the phone with Verizon "tech support" only to be told that they do not support such an application.  I believe the Arris router can do the job, but Verizon doesn't want to do that support at that level.  Is there a way to configure the Arris router so that my existing network can connect to the internet and work properly?

Comment: Set the Arris NVG558HX into bridge mode.

Comment: Or put it's static IP on the DMZ, but make sure you lock it down first!

Comment: Here is the Bridge setup but you need to be able to log into the modem. Verizon may not allow you.   https://arris.secure.force.com/consumers/articles/General_FAQs/TG862G-NA-Bridge-Mode-Setup

Comment: I've searched everywhere in the NVG558HX setup interface, and I cannot find a place to set the unit to bridge mode.  The NVG does not have the Lan Setting screen like the one in the example provided by John.

Comment: There is a setting for a "cascading router" which sounds like it would be applicable, but it won't let me enter the IP/subnet of my TPLink router.  I've changed the NVG IP/subnet, but I keep getting errors when I try to enter the TPLink info.  I'm sure it's operator error but unfortunately I know just enough about networking to get myself in trouble.  I'm going to keep trying but if I can't get it to work, I guess I'll have to return the NVG to Verizon and cancel the account.  I hate to think that I'm stuck with AT & T DSL for a while longer.

Comment: Did you find a solution?